# how to post jwt token with headers in php laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, http, jwt, header

here is the code:

```
$Response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'X-Jwt-Token'=>$tokenResponse['value']])->post($url.'/'.'certificates', $postData);
```

Am I doing it the right way? it does not give me expected results,
the same code works fine while using in zend:

```
$headers = array ('Content-Type:application/json', "X-Jwt-Token:$token");

$Response = $this->_apiServiceObj->excCurl ( $url . '/' . 'Certificates', '', $headers, $postData, 'POST' );
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: The [`Http::withToken`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http.html#method_withToken) method expects a `string` as the first argument, not an `array`.

Comment: Sorry the actual method is HTTP:: withHeaders and yes the first argument is a string

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi am not receiving the method body, but the status is success with 200 status code